# Intercepting logitech media keys

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I've bought a logitech bluetooth 'ipad tablet keyboard' for my windows pc, because I like the look of it.

The escape button is replaced with a key which opens the default browser search. It also has some issues where the hash key is missing, and there's no delete key.

I have circumvented these using a combination of 'KeyTweak', 'SharpKeys' and 'AutoHotkey' however none of these can stop that media button opening the browser.

Anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I'm assuming there is no intermediate Logitech program detecting/assigning these keys such as the Logitech SetPoint program (which may be another way to go, if one of the stock Logitech programs will let you re-assign the keys)

In AutoHotkey you should be able to make a hotkey to reassign it to Escape

```
Browser_Home::Send {Escape}
```

Or reassign it to nothing

```
Browser_Home::Return
```

The button name may not be `Browser_Home` though, depending on the keyboard setup... the best way to determine this is to open AutoHotkey once a script is running (use the icon in the tray) and then View > Key History.  Press the media button and then refresh the key history to see what key it registered as--that should allow you to reassign it correctly.

To see the full list of keynames supported (such as `Browser_Home`, `Launch_Media`, `Launch_App1`, etc.), look up the `key list` topic in help.

If you can view the key history correctly but still can't get a script to remap the button properly, post the relevant excerpt of the key history as an additional comment or update to your post.

Comment: Browser_Home worked, i'd been trying to assign to the key number directly. Thanks!